# Почему не работает корректно тест в ruby Minitest::Test?

Tags: ruby, юнит-тесты, test-automation, testng

Почему не работает корректно тест ?

```
 require 'minitest/autorun'


    class T
     attr_accessor :mass
     def v
     puts "zello #{mass}"   
    end  
    end

    class Mini< Minitest::Test
      def minitest
      f=T.new
      f.mass=12
      assert(f.v=="Hello Mari")
       end   
    end 
    Finished in 0.002298s, 0.0000 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

    0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: А вы как его запускали?

Comment: пожалуйста ответ Finished in 0.002298s, 0.0000 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

    0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Comment: ruby file.rb таким способом

Comment: как в книжки  в инете искал

Comment: Ок. А [документацию](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest#unit-tests) читали?

Comment: я вам говорил читал, разобрался, чуть позже вам расскажу

Comment: Ну, мне рассказывать не надо, я уже знаю ответ и дал вам на него ссылку выше. А вот оставить ответ стоило бы. Можете заняться.

Comment: да так дайте ссылку, получу дополнительные знания

Comment: Уже оставил выше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat t.rb 
class T

def initialize(mass)
      @mass = mass
  end

  def v
     puts "Hello #{@mass}"   
  end  
end
$ cat test_t.rb 
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 't'

class Mini< Minitest::Test
  def test_v
    f = T.new('Mari')
    assert_output("Hello Mari\n") {f.v}
  end   
end 
$ ruby test_t.rb 
Run options: --seed 63584

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.000819s, 1221.0006 runs/s, 1221.0006 assertions/s.

1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
$
```

Answer (score 0):

было бы неплохо переписать класс. `attr_accessor` применяется для переменны класса
и было бы хорошо создать конструктор вместо

файл `t.rb`

```
class T
  @mass
  attr_accessor :mass 

  def v
     puts "zello #{@mass}"   
  end  
end
```

тест методы должны начинаться с `test`
файл `test_t.rb`

```
 require 'minitest/autorun'
 require_relative 't'

 class Mini< Minitest::Test
      def test_v
      f=T.new
      f.mass=12
      assert(f.v=="Hello Mari")
       end   
    end
```

теперь можно запускать

`ruby test_t.rb`

```
Finished in 0.000947s, 1055.9667 runs/s, 1055.9667 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
Mini#test_v [2.rb:8]:
Expected false to be truthy.

1 runs, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: но он все равно, показывает что тест не пройден нормально, если мы даже запишем верные  данные.

Answer (score 0):

Все верно.

Он и не будет работать.

Надо поменять assert на assert_output(„expected”, f.v)

Comment: Все равно пишет ошибку (   1) Error:
Mini#test_v:
LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
    raz1.rb:9:in `test_v'

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips